# Linux commands for kids

Tags: command-line

My youngest daughter (6) is fascinated with the `sl` and `gti` commands. She even learned to combine them with `;` and when the time comes to teach her about return values I'll show her how `sl && gti` works but  `gti && sl` does not, as `gti` returns `1`.

What other commands might I teach her? She'll learn `ls` and other useful commands in time as she asks me to explain to her what I'm doing, but I'm looking for other fun commands such as `sl` and `gti`. `aafire` and `cowsay` are a bit entertaining, but if there are other exciting commands like `sl` and `gti` we'd love to know.

She says thanks!

Comment: [How about this?](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/11/50-linux-commands/)

Comment: This is really too broad for the site. It might make a good subject for [chat] though!

Comment: @terdon: In this particular case, if the question were so broad then the answer would be easy to find via Google. The fact that there are so few CLI applications which are just easter eggs or eye candy is the premise on which the value of the question stands.

Comment: @dotancohen I understand but asking for lists is basically off topic on all SE sites. There can be no single, authoritative answer which makes such questions a bad fit for the SE model. By the way, I doff my hat to your 6-year-old. Sounds like one smart cookie!

Comment: @terdon - this question shouldn't have been closed - at least not single-handedly. If 5 users with enough reputation agree with you then it will be closed, but if not there is no call to beat on kids with your mod-hammer. Take it easy, man.

Comment: @mikeserv I refer you to the [Help Center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) which clearly states that questions where "there's no specific problem to be solved" and "every answer is equally valid" are not welcome here. You can also see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/203101) by an SE employee who explains why list questions are not wanted.

Comment: dotancohen - when i was a kid my grandpa bought me a Logo interpreter. I used it to write little scripts for moving the turtle around the screen. [UCBLogo](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/logo.html) is a freeware *(and supposed to be among the best anyway)* Logo interpreter that should work in X - and it comes with its own cli.

Comment: @terdon - there is a specific problem to be solved, and not every answer would be valid. The problem is engaging a child proactively with a Unix environment, and so probably 95% of command-line utilities would be invalid for that purpose.

Comment: @terdon - so you see? While you have your perspective on the matter, I have another. And this is why it should take ***5 reputable users*** to close a question. Bringing moderator powers to bear is understandable where spam or other sorts of abuse are concerned, but why in the world would you do it for a simple question about entertaining children?

Comment: Check out Debian Edu, perhaps?

Comment: A recent blog post shares some additional goodies: [Fun at the UNIX Terminal](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1483).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

-- If she has started with basic math, she may like `bc` or `python` command prompt.

-- You can write her a simple interactive, menu driven script to do counting or printing alphabets in fancy and colorful fonts.

-- I recall I played a game called `hangman` a while ago. You can remove complicated words from the dictionary and add simple ones.

-- Editor: You may open up an editor (nano, may be) for her and let her write what she feels like writing.

-- Bell: You can write aliases to make fancy bell sounds

-- Chat: If you are at work, can use command line chat or mail to exchange goofy messages.

This is all I can think of.

Comment: Thanks. Her older sister (8) does write some Python, in fact we are together writing Hangman. I like the idea of having her make the different bell sounds. In fact, that looks like a great answer for the question, thanks.